# Neo4j get information of TransactionEventHandler

Tags: java, exception, neo4j, eventhandler

Is there a way to retrieve the information (writeSet of Transaction) out of the TransactionEventHandler?

```
public class NewTransactionEventHandler<T> implements TransactionEventHandler<T>
{

    @Override
    public T beforeCommit(TransactionData transactionData)
```

I'd like to get that transactionData Object after the transaction           finished successfully or unsuccessfully

Answer (score 1):

[`TransactionEventHandler.afterCommit`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html#afterCommit(org.neo4j.graphdb.event.TransactionData,%20T)) and [`TransactionEventHandler.afterRollback`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html#afterRollback(org.neo4j.graphdb.event.TransactionData,%20T)) is probably what you're looking for. [`TransactionData`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionData.html) gives you access to the changes.

Comment: And they return they're result to what location?  TX . terminate and TX.Success?

Comment: don't understand your comment. Regardless if the tx is successful, `beforeCommit` is called. Depending wether the tx is  successful or not, either `afterCommit` or `afterRollback` is called.

Comment: That is correct,  but how may I access the transactionData outside of the transactionHandler.  How do I return it,  and where can I return it to.

Comment: You need to create and register your own `TransactionEventHandler` that might extract the relevant pieces out of `TransactionData` and store it somewhere (maybe a thread local ?). Be aware that TransactionData itself might be invalid when consumed outside a tx event handler.

Comment: I created and registered the handler,  I took the relevant information and retrieved it in an own variable.  Now I need to get the information into the class where I executed the transaction.

Comment: You can declare the ThreadLocal inside your TransactionEventHandler. When establishing the event handler, maintain a reference to it in a singleton like context.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to set a Variable

```
public class NewTransactionEventHandler<T> implements TransactionEventHandler<T>
{
public int returnVariable = 0;
}
```

When you register the EventHandler

```
saveEventHandler= graphDb1.registerTransactionEventHandler(EventHandler);
```

you can access the eventHandler to get the data:

```
saveEventHandler.returnVariable;
```

Comment: That's potentially dangerous since the transaction event handler might get called concurrent from different threads. So you don't know to which transaction the `returnVariable` is associated to.

Comment: It is not a problem if I only have 1 transaction thread running.